# Cakephp query failed to update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm very new to Cakephp'
I tried to get post data and update the invoice table. But I'm supposed to get value of doctor id from post data and get the referral fee relevant to doctor id from doctor table and the update invoice table.

i tried with this code but didn't works. please help  me out.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    $this->Invoice->create();
    if ($this->Invoice->save($this->request->data)) {
        $refid = $this->request->data['Invoice']['refid'];  
        print_r($refid);
        $doctor = $this->Doctor->findById($refid);
        $rfee = $doctor['Doctor']['rfee'];
        $invoice_number = $this->request->data['Invoice']['invoice_number'];
        $invoice = $this->Invoice->findByInvoiceNumber($invoice_number);
        $invoice_id = $invoice['Invoice']['id'];
        $this->Invoice->id = $invoice_id;
        $this->Invoice->save('refee', '200');
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invoice Successfully Added');

        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'invoices', 'action' => 'edit', $invoice_id));
   } else {
       $this->Session->setFlash('Unable To Add Invoice');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to update record by this

```
$this->Invoice->save($this->request->data,false);
```

if record updated successfully then its mean there is some validation rule failed regarding your posted data. if this issue don't solve by this way then check PK of invoice table exist in your POST data if not then set it & re-run your code

Comment: actually what i want is after getting updated with post data in the invoice table, get the rfee from doctor table with respect to refid in the post data and update with previous updated invoice table